# ubuntu fails to load the graphical interface-- BLACKSCREEN, ALL TTYs working

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, upstart, systemd

I recently changed my entire machine and i just swapped my ssd in the new machine. grub2 works and shows my options, when i choose (k)ubuntu, it will end up in an empty black screen, however, when i do Ctrl+ALT+[F1-F6] all shells are running. when i issue `sudo init 5` or `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target` the login manager successfully shows up and everything works, upstart works as well. I did a update-grub, but this doesn't at all look like a grub issue. i don't know how to fix the normal process so i wont have to do this every time.

Please let me know if i can provide more info.

Comment: What does this command show you from one of the terminals logged in as root (or using sudo)? `systemctl get-default`

Comment: Oh, also, `systemctl list-jobs` should show if it's waiting on some particular service causing a hang.

Comment: so, ... get-default,  it actually shows graphical.target!  the problem is , it actually works when i do 'init 5' or 'systemctl isolate graphi .."

Comment: To confirm that this is indeed a graphics issue, you might want to set `nomodeset` in grub (e.g., `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`). This will prevent mode switching into your video chipset driver.